# getting response.message blank in case of status 500 in retrofit okhttp

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to integrate one custom webservice using `Retrofit` and `Okhttp3`. That custom webservie throws HTTP Status code 500 and send the HTTP Status Messagess in two different scenarios.

1. 500 status code with "Token Expire" message
2. 500 status code with "Model Number does not exist" message

**POSTMAN Screenshot**

I can see status code and message in POSTMAN but when I try to use it in android with `Retrofit` and `Okhttp3` it always sends a message as blank.

[image]

**Androdi Screenshot**

[image]

**For simplycity have added this Code Sample**

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build();
    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, " {\"applicationVersion\":\"1.0\",\"fileType\":\"2\",\"modelNo\":\"ABC\",\"userRequestInfo\":[{\"isVerified\":false,\"userId\":\"yRouP/4yHG8RWwVps/WrBQ==\"}]}");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://demo")
            .method("POST", body)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer zerJtPLvz2UgD6C3LwY0vO1SvYvkzfgkdZO2gC+Zdyw=")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
         
            .build();


         client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {

                Log.e(TAG,response.message());
            }
        });



}
```

Comment: What does `response.errorBody()` return?

Comment: it returns some HTML body with error but we are ignoring that